# How to update index in mysql when a row is deleted

Tags: mysql

really sorry if someone already asked this question, I couldn't find it and I'm stuck with it. 
So if I have three records in table car :

1 | Maserati | red

2 | Ferarri  | red

3 | Audi     | blue

...and I delete Ferarri record, I'm left with :

1 | Maserati | red
3 | Audi     | blue

Is there a way to have this table automatically indexed as such :

1 | Maserati | red
2 | Audi     | blue

Note: I have an index column which is set to autoincrement.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: mysql will be recalculating indexes automatically